# It possible to accesses module memory space from another module?

Tags: javascript, webassembly

There is any way to pass to wasm module, a memory space of another wasm module?
I read that with dynamic linking it possible to share the memory space, but I did not found anything that explain how to do that.

```
https://webassembly.org/docs/dynamic-linking/
```

I also read about globals, but it seems that its not possible to declare Unit32Array as global. (correct me if i wrong)

Working with copies are not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any wasm module can import or exports its memory.   Today wasm modules only support a single memory, so order to shared a memory you can either created the memory object in JavaScript have have both wasm module import it.  Or have one module export the the memory and the other import it.

In emscripten this is how the MAIN_MODULE/SIDE_MODULE version of dynamic linking is implemented: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Linking

Comment: So from what i undestand, there is no way to do that if a wish that both module have a different memory space?